# Где Ошибка? SyntaxError: expression expected after dictionary key and ':'

Tags: python

```
 context = {
    'title' : 'Store',
    'header' : 'Добро пожаловать!',
    'username' : 'Ивав Иванов',
    'products' : [
        {'name' : 'Худи черного цвета с монограммами adidas Originals' , 'price' : 6090.00},
        {'name' : 'Синяя куртка The North Face' , 'price' : 23725.00},
        {'name' : 'Коричневый спортивный oversized-топ ASOS DESIGN' , 'price' : 3390.00},
    ],
    'promotion' : True ,
    'products_of_promotion' : [
        {'name' : 'Черный рюкзак Nike Heritage' , 'price' : 2 340.00}
    ]
}
```

Где ошибка?

Comment: вставь код в нормальную ИДЕ и она сразу подсветит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
'products_of_promotion' : [
        {'name' : 'Черный рюкзак Nike Heritage' , 'price' : 2 340.00} # здесь слитно цифры напишите
    ]
```

Вот так

```py
'price' : 2340.00}
```

а вообще любое IDE спокойно увидит, где у вас ошибка